# Way to add more than 1 item to createtextnode

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this here and all I'm wondering is under
`document.createTextNode(addLocation.name);` 
How do I add more than one item? For example, would it work if i did
     `document.createTextNode(addLocation.name, addLocation.description)`?

```
function locationcardload(){

var allLocations = document.getElementById("locationList");
;


rawTxt = localStorage.getItem("locations")
LocationArray = JSON.parse(rawTxt);
;

    for (var x=0; x<LocationArray.length; x++) {
    var addLocation = LocationArray[x];
    var additem = document.createElement("div")


    additem.classname = "icon";        
    additem.className = "item";
;
    var LocListText = document.createTextNode(addLocation.name);
        additem.appendChild(LocListText);
        allLocations.appendChild(additem);
      }
}
```

Comment: You're only creating one textNode from the string passed in, so you could do something like ... `.createTextNode(value1 + value2)` instead

Comment: @adeneo that didn't seem to work, I get an error in the console; "addlocation is not defined"

Comment: Then you should define it? What are all those semicolons for btw ?

Comment: @adeneo Honestly I just realised they were there (I'm still fairly new to JavaScript).  Yeah, "addlocation" is definitely a variable I have and so I don't know why it wouldn't be defined unless I've made a small mistake somewhhere

Comment: Look at the error in the console, it should give you a location, line number or something, and then look at that line of code and try to figure out why the variable wouldn't be accessible in that place.

Comment: `addlocation !== addLocation`.

Comment: [*createTextNode*](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-document-createtextnode) has one optional parameter, the text to place in the node. Any additional parameters will be ignored.